# How to merge and update node of a list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

I know there are tons of generic questions on this topic on SO. Even I tried bunch of them, but no success. 
Here is my little code for merging

```
var existingFileDetails = XmlParser<NcSyncManifestXml>.Deserialize(RemoteManifestFile).Files;
var newList = existingFileDetails
   .Union(updatedFileDetails)
   .OrderByDescending(c => c.LastModifiedDate)
   .ToList();
```

I have two list, i.e. `List<FileDetails>.` 
FileDetails is a class that has three things `Name, Md5Hash, LastModified`. Here I have two lists,

```
List<FileDetails> UpdatedList = having 4-5 items of modified files, 
and another 
List<FileDetails> ExistingList = having 100 files
```

### Scenario

The files in `UpdatedList` may exist in `ExistingList`. If they do exists they have different

```
1. MD5Hash and 
2. LastModifiedDate
```

### Requirement [UPDATED]

Assume:
`ExistingList  = {[{FileName=xyx.txt,MD5=1,LastModified=12/12/2013}], [{FileName=abc.txt,MD5=11,LastModified=12/13/2013}],[{FileName=def.txt,MD5=111,LastModified=12/14/2013}],
[{FileName=detf.txt,MD5=1111,LastModified=12/14/2013}]}`

Now I receive a new list of updated files in which abc.txt and def.txt have changes and a new file added Run.txt

`UpdatedList ={[{FileName=abc.txt,MD5=1fsd431,LastModified=12/16/2013}],[{FileName=def.txt,MD5=asdasd34243,LastModified=12/16/2013}]},[{FileName=Run.txt,MD5=sdf45sdf4545asdasd34243,LastModified=12/16/2013}]}`

So my new resultant list after merge will be

`NewList ={[{FileName=xyx.txt,MD5=1,LastModified=12/12/2013}], [{FileName=abc.txt,MD5=1fsd431,LastModified=12/16/2013}], // updated abc and def [{FileName=def.txt,MD5=asdasd34243,LastModified=12/16/2013}], //they have different md5 and date in UpdatedList
[{FileName=detf.txt,MD5=1111,LastModified=12/14/2013}]}}]},[{FileName=Run.txt,MD5=sdf45sdf4545asdasd34243,LastModified=12/16/2013}]}` // new file added

### Issue

Above piece of code merges data but not update it. Need you guys to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overload of the `Union` linq operator that takes an `IEqualityComparer`, so that it can see when two objects are (semantically in this case) the same. Since we always prefer the updated file details here, we can position this on the left hand side of the operator to make sure they're preferred over the existing file details.

```
var newList = updatedFileDetails
    .Union(existingFileDetails, new FileParametersComparer())
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.LastModifiedDate)
    .ToList();
```

File parameters comparer would look something like this - here I'm using the `Name` property to check if it's referring to the same file, though you can do whatever you need to.

```
public class FileParametersComparer : IEqualityComparer<FileDetails>
{
    public bool Equals(FileDetails x, FileDetails y)
    {
        return x.Name.Equals(y.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FileDetails obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AtJQvy

Comment: @AmitRanjan I don't see how your update invalidates this answer. Did you notice he swapped `updatedFileDetails` and `existingFileDetails` in his call of `Union`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quick and dirty by changing your list temporarily to a Dictionary:

```
var tmpDict = ExistingList.ToDictionary(x => x.FileName);
foreach (var item in UpdatedList)
{
    tmpDict[item.FileName] = item;
}

var newList = tmpDict.Select(x => x.Value).OrderByDescending(c => c.LastModified).ToList();
```